# How to print invoice reference in each invoice page for only invoices report?

Tags: report, odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I need the show invoice reference on invoice report in header. which is just like that  "Draft Invoice: ~ AR-2018/0303". It is on the first page only and i need to display on every page.

I try to that: ~

```
 <template id="external_layout_header_inherited" inherit_id="report.external_layout_header">
    <xpath expr="//div[@class='header']" position="inside">
        <div t-if="o.number">Ref.: <span t-field="o.number"/></div>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

But when I print the other Report Just like Sale or Purchase It effect all the report.

So, My Question is that how to print invoice reference on Invoice report  starting of Second page also?

Answer (score 1):

You are in the right way, but in your invoice report, you need call a custom external_layout that call a custom header like this

```
<t t-call="report.external_layout_custom">
    <t t-call="report.external_layout_header_custom" />
        <t t-raw="0" />
        <t t-call="report.external_layout_footer_custom" />
    </t>
</t>
```